# How do I debug an Azure Function locally with Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I've got a C# TimerTrigger Azure Function but cannot F5 in to it and hit a breakpoint. Every time I try I'm met with:

```
[7/12/2017 7:39:52 PM] Job host started
Error: listen EACCES 0.0.0.0:5858
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
    at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1240:19)
    at listen (net.js:1289:10)
    at net.js:1399:9
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
```

Which looks an awfully lot like a firewall exception. I've allowed func.exe thru, as well as the offending (or so it seems) port 5858 but neither have helped.

Comment: Are you running VS with administrative priviledge?

Comment: I wasn't, no, and turns out I don't need to. It just started working. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

After a reboot of my machine and no other changes, F5 in an Azure Functions app is working successfully.

Would be nice if anybody could help get to the bottom of what would have been causing this error, though.